# I am trying to get data from the related tables in the database using sails js. But I always get undefined error. Thank you

Tags: node.js, database, find, sails.js, populate

TransmitterController

```
 transmitter: function (req, res) {
    Transmitter.find().populate('TrceiverId').exec(function (errr, transmitter) {
      Tranceiver.find().exec(function (err, tranceiver) {
        res.view('pages/transmitter', {layout: "layouts/layout", 'transmitter': transmitter, 'tranceiver': tranceiver})
      });
    })
  },
```

I'm trying to pull data from the database but the answer is: undefined

Model tranceiver

```
module.exports = {
                datastore: 'mysql',
          tableName: 'tranceiver',
          attributes: {
            id: { type: 'number', unique: true, autoIncrement: true, columnName: 'trnsId' },
            Name: { type: 'string', required: true, columnName: 'Name' },
            Feature: { type: 'string', required: true, columnName: 'Feature'}
  },

};
```

Model Transmitter

```
 module.exports = {
  datastore:'mysql',
  tableName:'transmitter',
  attributes: {
    id:{type:'number',unique:true,autoIncrement:true,columnName:'trnsId'},
    Name:{type:'string',required:true,columnName:'Name'},
    TrceiverId:{model:'Tranceiver'}
  },
};
```

I am waiting for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your collection transmitter has correct TrceiverId in them. I tried same with mongodb and got correct result when used correct TrceiverId in my collections.

Comment: I did not find a solution. I tried to shrink the database and try again, but it did not. please help me

Comment: TypeError: C:\Users\ersin\Desktop\nodeJS\iotPdks\views\pages\transmitter.ejs:39
    37|               <thead>
    38|                 <tr>
 >> 39|                    <% if (transmitter.length > 0) {
    40|                     var columnsIn = transmitter[0];
    41|                     for(var key in columnsIn){
    42|                     if(key=="id"){

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at compile

Comment: Seems like transmitter is undefined.